# Does this paragraph contain a comma error?

Tags: commas, independent-clauses, coordinating-conjunctions

Should there be a comma before the coordinating conjunction 'and' in this paragraph?

*"The High court determined that no contract
existed between the two parties because under an objective
standard, a reasonable person could tell that no offer was
intended **and** the alleged contract was void because it was
for goods above $ 1200.00 and not in writing."*

Comment: There is, first of all, a comma missing after 'because'. Welcome to EL&U.

Comment: @Nigel J Why a comma after "because" on the first line?

Comment: @Nigel J: Alternatively, *remove* the comma after ***standard***. It's a stylistic choice whether to set off the parenthetical clause in commas or not (though we usually *would*, with a long-ish clause in a relatively complex sentence like this).

Comment: Uh… others might and I don't believe that's a quotation, unless it comes from a scarcely literate journal.

Almost the only thing clear about that passage is that it should use "… intended. The alleged… "

Almost everything else brands it as not being written by a literate native speaker.